# Não consigo deixar o footer em baixo

Tags: css, html5

Meu HTML e CSS:

```css
body {
 background-image: url(img/fundonew.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 font-family: Arial;
 background-color: #003013;
}

#main {
 position: absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:50%;
 width: 770px;
 margin-left: -450px;


}

#logo {
 position: absolute;
 top:0px;
 left: -100px;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;

}
#btinicio {
 position: absolute;
 top:60px;
 left:340px;
 width: auto;
 height: 33px;
}
#btaquecimento {
 position: absolute;
 top:60px;
 left:470px;
 width: auto;
 height: 33px;
}
#btefeito {
 position: absolute;
 top:60px;
 left:670px;
 width: auto;
 height: 33px;
}
#btea {
 position: absolute;
 top:60px;
 left:810px;
 width: auto;
 height: 33px;
}
#conteudo {
 position: relative;
 top:150px;
 left:2px;
 width:900px;
 height: auto;
 background-color: #bcc1ad;
 color: #0024ff;
}

#conteudo p{
 font-size:20px;
 text-align: justify;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px; 
}

#footer {
 position:absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Educãção Ambiental</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="main"> 
   <div id="logo">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logoofc.png" border="0"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="btinicio">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/inicio1.png" border="0" onMouseOver="this.src='img/inicio2.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/inicio1.png'"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="btaquecimento">
    <a href="aquecimento.html"><img src="img/aquecimento2.png" border="0" onMouseOver="this.src='img/aquecimento3.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/aquecimento2.png'"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="btefeito">
    <a href="efeito.html"><img src="img/efeito1.png" border="0" onMouseOver="this.src='img/efeito2png.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/efeito1.png'"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="btea">
    <a href="ea.html"><img src="img/ea2.png" border="0" onMouseOver="this.src='img/ea3.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/ea2.png'"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="conteudo">
    <h2> 
     O planeta pede socorro
    </h2>
    <p>
     Falta d'água. Falta de energia. Falta de área verde. Tudo isso gerado pela falta de consciência das pessoas. 
     <br>
     <br>
     Estamos começando a sentir o mal que a Terra sente há anos, o elevado uso dos recursos naturais do Planeta está sobrecarregando-o, ultrapassando o limite, e se não respeitado esse limite, o que poderá ocorrer futuramente ?
    </p>
    <p>
     A reciclagem é uma de várias maneiras que podem ser colocada é prática para solucionar alguns problemas ambientais, é necessário que sempre tenhamos em mente que não devemos jogar lixo em qualquer lugar, um exemplo claro, é o lixo eletrônico.
     <br>
     <br>
     Hoje milhares de pessoas tem celular, e por causa da rápida obsolescência desses equipamentos, é comum jogarmos eles nos lixos de casa ou da rua, porém, é um hábito errado, que pode trazer várias doenças e impactos ambientais, o certo seria levar para estabelecimentos que fazem esse tipo de reciclagem para que não ocorra esses casos. 
     <br>
     <br>
     A poluição do ar é preocupante , a emissão de CO2 aumenta a cada ano, entretanto, esse é um problema que só pode ser combatido em conjunto, ao invés de usar carros ou motos para sair, pode-se usar as bicicletas, pois além de fazer bem para a saúde, minimiza a emissão de dióxido de carbono na atmosfera. 
     <br>
     <br>
     Fica claro, portanto, que os nossos maus hábitos estão trazendo inúmeros problemas ambientais que só podem ser resolvidos em conjunto. 
     <br>
     <br>
     A mídia é um importante fator nesse cenário, pois ela precisa denunciar e esclarecer a sociedade sobre as nossas atitudes, mostrar os problemas que estamos gerando e o que poderá acontecer se não mudarmos os nossos hábitos. 
     <br>
     <br>
     O governo deve criar medidas que cesse a poluição e o consumo exagerado. E é necessário que cada indivíduo tenha consciência do que está acontecendo e respeite o meio ambiente, evitando desperdício e reduzindo embalagens, porque o "planeta pede socorro".
    </p>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
    <h1>Desenvolvido pelo grupo: Shadow - Para a semana Paulo Freire</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, como você está usando somente divs com "position:absolute", é só você setar o atributo "margin-top" com o valor total da altura dos demais conteúdos, fiz esse exemplo:

https://jsfiddle.net/q1wf5kLv/

Isso resolve seu problema nesse momento, entretanto, há muito a agregar, pois você não pode trabalhar um documento web dessa forma engessada, pois um dos recursos mais ricos da web é você poder redimensionar (é o que chamamos de site responsivo) sua aplicação para diversas formas de resolução.

Para começar, recomendo você tentar reescrever seu código com as colunas do Bootstrap, pois deixam o documento padronizado de forma mais profissional e auto ajustável para mobile. Aqui um tutorial legal: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Espero ter ajudado, abraços

Comment: Oii boa noite, muito obrigado pelo ajuda. Sou iniciante na área, você me salvou. Já estava quase desistindo haha

Comment: hahaha, não desista parceiro! Pega o bootstrap p/ facilitar a vida do layout, aí você não precisa editar o css para editar o layout, só usar as classes; só sucesso. Se puder mandar thumbs up. Abs e boa sorte com seu projeto

Answer (score 0):

Fiz algumas modificações no seu `css` e consertei o problema do `footer`.  Você tinha vários elementos posicionados de forma absoluta, inclusive o `#main`. Eu apenas removi o estilo de `#main`, o `position:absolute` do `footer` e algumas propriedades do `#conteudo`.

Segue o código modificado:

```css
body {
 background-image: url(img/fundonew.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 font-family: Arial;
 background-color: #003013;
}

#logo {
 position: absolute;
 top:0px;
 left: -100px;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;

}
#btinicio {
 position: absolute;
 top:60px;
 left:340px;
 width: auto;
 height: 33px;
}
#btaquecimento {
 position: absolute;
 top:60px;
 left:470px;
 width: auto;
 height: 33px;
}
#btefeito {
 position: absolute;
 top:60px;
 left:670px;
 width: auto;
 height: 33px;
}
#btea {
 position: absolute;
 top:60px;
 left:810px;
 width: auto;
 height: 33px;
}

#conteudo {
 position: relative;
 margin-top:150px;
 background-color: #bcc1ad;
 color: #0024ff;
}

#conteudo p{
 font-size:20px;
 text-align: justify;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px; 
}

#footer {
 bottom: 0px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Educãção Ambiental</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="main"> 
   <div id="logo">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logoofc.png" border="0"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="btinicio">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/inicio1.png" border="0" onMouseOver="this.src='img/inicio2.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/inicio1.png'"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="btaquecimento">
    <a href="aquecimento.html"><img src="img/aquecimento2.png" border="0" onMouseOver="this.src='img/aquecimento3.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/aquecimento2.png'"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="btefeito">
    <a href="efeito.html"><img src="img/efeito1.png" border="0" onMouseOver="this.src='img/efeito2png.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/efeito1.png'"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="btea">
    <a href="ea.html"><img src="img/ea2.png" border="0" onMouseOver="this.src='img/ea3.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/ea2.png'"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="conteudo">
    <h2> 
     O planeta pede socorro
    </h2>
    <p>
     Falta d'água. Falta de energia. Falta de área verde. Tudo isso gerado pela falta de consciência das pessoas. 
     <br>
     <br>
     Estamos começando a sentir o mal que a Terra sente há anos, o elevado uso dos recursos naturais do Planeta está sobrecarregando-o, ultrapassando o limite, e se não respeitado esse limite, o que poderá ocorrer futuramente ?
    </p>
    <p>
     A reciclagem é uma de várias maneiras que podem ser colocada é prática para solucionar alguns problemas ambientais, é necessário que sempre tenhamos em mente que não devemos jogar lixo em qualquer lugar, um exemplo claro, é o lixo eletrônico.
     <br>
     <br>
     Hoje milhares de pessoas tem celular, e por causa da rápida obsolescência desses equipamentos, é comum jogarmos eles nos lixos de casa ou da rua, porém, é um hábito errado, que pode trazer várias doenças e impactos ambientais, o certo seria levar para estabelecimentos que fazem esse tipo de reciclagem para que não ocorra esses casos. 
     <br>
     <br>
     A poluição do ar é preocupante , a emissão de CO2 aumenta a cada ano, entretanto, esse é um problema que só pode ser combatido em conjunto, ao invés de usar carros ou motos para sair, pode-se usar as bicicletas, pois além de fazer bem para a saúde, minimiza a emissão de dióxido de carbono na atmosfera. 
     <br>
     <br>
     Fica claro, portanto, que os nossos maus hábitos estão trazendo inúmeros problemas ambientais que só podem ser resolvidos em conjunto. 
     <br>
     <br>
     A mídia é um importante fator nesse cenário, pois ela precisa denunciar e esclarecer a sociedade sobre as nossas atitudes, mostrar os problemas que estamos gerando e o que poderá acontecer se não mudarmos os nossos hábitos. 
     <br>
     <br>
     O governo deve criar medidas que cesse a poluição e o consumo exagerado. E é necessário que cada indivíduo tenha consciência do que está acontecendo e respeite o meio ambiente, evitando desperdício e reduzindo embalagens, porque o "planeta pede socorro".
    </p>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
    <h1>Desenvolvido pelo grupo: Shadow - Para a semana Paulo Freire</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Percebi que você tá tentando sempre posicionar os elementos de forma absoluta na tela. Isso é um problema, você deve sempre pensar que as telas têm tamanhos diferentes e que um layout dessa forma é muito difícil de manter.