# Como faço para o conteudo e rodapé respeitar o topo?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

**Estou com um problema, meu conteudo e rodape n respeita o logo e o menu. Como poderia resolver esse problema?**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
body {
 background-image: url(img/fundonew.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 font-family: Arial;
 background-color: #003013;
}

#main {
 min-height:100%; 
    position:relative; 
    width:1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

#logo {
 position: absolute;
 top:0px;
 left: -100px;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;

}
#btinicio {
 position: absolute;
 top:60px;
 left:340px;
 width: auto;
 height: 33px;
}
#btaquecimento {
 position: absolute;
 top:60px;
 left:470px;
 width: auto;
 height: 33px;
}
#btefeito {
 position: absolute;
 top:60px;
 left:670px;
 width: auto;
 height: 33px;
}
#btea {
 position: absolute;
 top:60px;
 left:810px;
 width: auto;
 height: 33px;
}
#conteudo {
 width: 100%;
 top:-150px;
    background: #cccccc;   
}

#conteudo p{
 font-size:20px;
 text-align: justify;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px; 
}

#footer{    
    background: #3C948B;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0; 
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Educãção Ambiental</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="main"> 
   <div id="logo">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logoofc.png" border="0"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="btinicio">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/inicio1.png" border="0" onMouseOver="this.src='img/inicio2.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/inicio1.png'"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="btaquecimento">
    <a href="aquecimento.html"><img src="img/aquecimento2.png" border="0" onMouseOver="this.src='img/aquecimento3.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/aquecimento2.png'"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="btefeito">
    <a href="efeito.html"><img src="img/efeito1.png" border="0" onMouseOver="this.src='img/efeito2png.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/efeito1.png'"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="btea">
    <a href="ea.html"><img src="img/ea2.png" border="0" onMouseOver="this.src='img/ea3.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/ea2.png'"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="conteudo">
    <h2> 
     O planeta pede socorro
    </h2>
    <p>
     Falta d'água. Falta de energia. Falta de área verde. Tudo isso gerado pela falta de consciência das pessoas. 
     <br>
     <br>
     Estamos começando a sentir o mal que a Terra sente há anos, o elevado uso dos recursos naturais do Planeta está sobrecarregando-o, ultrapassando o limite, e se não respeitado esse limite, o que poderá ocorrer futuramente ?
    </p>
    <p>
     A reciclagem é uma de várias maneiras que podem ser colocada é prática para solucionar alguns problemas ambientais, é necessário que sempre tenhamos em mente que não devemos jogar lixo em qualquer lugar, um exemplo claro, é o lixo eletrônico.
     <br>
     <br>
     Hoje milhares de pessoas tem celular, e por causa da rápida obsolescência desses equipamentos, é comum jogarmos eles nos lixos de casa ou da rua, porém, é um hábito errado, que pode trazer várias doenças e impactos ambientais, o certo seria levar para estabelecimentos que fazem esse tipo de reciclagem para que não ocorra esses casos. 
     <br>
     <br>
     A poluição do ar é preocupante , a emissão de CO2 aumenta a cada ano, entretanto, esse é um problema que só pode ser combatido em conjunto, ao invés de usar carros ou motos para sair, pode-se usar as bicicletas, pois além de fazer bem para a saúde, minimiza a emissão de dióxido de carbono na atmosfera. 
     <br>
     <br>
     Fica claro, portanto, que os nossos maus hábitos estão trazendo inúmeros problemas ambientais que só podem ser resolvidos em conjunto. 
     <br>
     <br>
     A mídia é um importante fator nesse cenário, pois ela precisa denunciar e esclarecer a sociedade sobre as nossas atitudes, mostrar os problemas que estamos gerando e o que poderá acontecer se não mudarmos os nossos hábitos. 
     <br>
     <br>
     O governo deve criar medidas que cesse a poluição e o consumo exagerado. E é necessário que cada indivíduo tenha consciência do que está acontecendo e respeite o meio ambiente, evitando desperdício e reduzindo embalagens, porque o "planeta pede socorro".
    </p>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
    <h1>Desenvolvido pelo grupo: Shadow - Para a semana Paulo Freire</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não é a mesma pergunta que fez em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/381423/n%c3%a3o-consigo-deixar-o-footer-em-baixo?

Comment: Não foi eu que fiz essa pergunta n

Comment: Link corrigido...

Comment: Com a ajuda do pessoal eu consegui resolver o problema do rodapé, mas agr o topo fica em cima do conteudo, gostaria que o conteudo e o rodapé respeitasse esse espaço :(

Answer (score 0):

Seu CSS está meio confuso, mas o que tá gerando esse conflito são esses position: absolute; que vc está declarando em todas as DIVs. E quando tiver usando o float: Left ou float: right, para não da conflito com o próximo conteúdo coloque clear: both;

Answer (score 0):

Como você está usando `position absolute` nos elementos do menu (incluindo a logo), esses elementos não ocupam espaço na página. Você pode resolver colocando um `padding-top` na `div#main` com um valor suficiente para que crie um espaço na parte de cima da div de modo que o conteúdo não fique por baixo do menu:

```
#main {
    padding-top: 180px; /* AQUI */
    min-height:100%; 
    position:relative; 
    width:1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

No exemplo acima coloquei `180px`, levando em consideração que sua logo possui `150px` de altura, dando uma margem de `30px` entre a logo e o conteúdo, mas esse valor você pode ajustar como achar melhor.

```css
body {
 background-image: url(img/fundonew.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 font-family: Arial;
 background-color: #003013;
}

#main {
  padding-top: 180px;
 min-height:100%; 
    position:relative; 
    width:1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

#logo {
 position: absolute;
 top:0px;
 left: -100px;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;

}
#btinicio {
 position: absolute;
 top:60px;
 left:340px;
 width: auto;
 height: 33px;
}
#btaquecimento {
 position: absolute;
 top:60px;
 left:470px;
 width: auto;
 height: 33px;
}
#btefeito {
 position: absolute;
 top:60px;
 left:670px;
 width: auto;
 height: 33px;
}
#btea {
 position: absolute;
 top:60px;
 left:810px;
 width: auto;
 height: 33px;
}
#conteudo {
 width: 100%;
 top:-150px;
    background: #cccccc;   
}

#conteudo p{
 font-size:20px;
 text-align: justify;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px; 
}

#footer{    
    background: #3C948B;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0; 
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Educãção Ambiental</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="main"> 
   <div id="logo">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logoofc.png" border="0"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="btinicio">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/inicio1.png" border="0" onMouseOver="this.src='img/inicio2.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/inicio1.png'"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="btaquecimento">
    <a href="aquecimento.html"><img src="img/aquecimento2.png" border="0" onMouseOver="this.src='img/aquecimento3.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/aquecimento2.png'"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="btefeito">
    <a href="efeito.html"><img src="img/efeito1.png" border="0" onMouseOver="this.src='img/efeito2png.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/efeito1.png'"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="btea">
    <a href="ea.html"><img src="img/ea2.png" border="0" onMouseOver="this.src='img/ea3.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/ea2.png'"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="conteudo">
    <h2> 
     O planeta pede socorro
    </h2>
    <p>
     Falta d'água. Falta de energia. Falta de área verde. Tudo isso gerado pela falta de consciência das pessoas. 
     <br>
     <br>
     Estamos começando a sentir o mal que a Terra sente há anos, o elevado uso dos recursos naturais do Planeta está sobrecarregando-o, ultrapassando o limite, e se não respeitado esse limite, o que poderá ocorrer futuramente ?
    </p>
    <p>
     A reciclagem é uma de várias maneiras que podem ser colocada é prática para solucionar alguns problemas ambientais, é necessário que sempre tenhamos em mente que não devemos jogar lixo em qualquer lugar, um exemplo claro, é o lixo eletrônico.
     <br>
     <br>
     Hoje milhares de pessoas tem celular, e por causa da rápida obsolescência desses equipamentos, é comum jogarmos eles nos lixos de casa ou da rua, porém, é um hábito errado, que pode trazer várias doenças e impactos ambientais, o certo seria levar para estabelecimentos que fazem esse tipo de reciclagem para que não ocorra esses casos. 
     <br>
     <br>
     A poluição do ar é preocupante , a emissão de CO2 aumenta a cada ano, entretanto, esse é um problema que só pode ser combatido em conjunto, ao invés de usar carros ou motos para sair, pode-se usar as bicicletas, pois além de fazer bem para a saúde, minimiza a emissão de dióxido de carbono na atmosfera. 
     <br>
     <br>
     Fica claro, portanto, que os nossos maus hábitos estão trazendo inúmeros problemas ambientais que só podem ser resolvidos em conjunto. 
     <br>
     <br>
     A mídia é um importante fator nesse cenário, pois ela precisa denunciar e esclarecer a sociedade sobre as nossas atitudes, mostrar os problemas que estamos gerando e o que poderá acontecer se não mudarmos os nossos hábitos. 
     <br>
     <br>
     O governo deve criar medidas que cesse a poluição e o consumo exagerado. E é necessário que cada indivíduo tenha consciência do que está acontecendo e respeite o meio ambiente, evitando desperdício e reduzindo embalagens, porque o "planeta pede socorro".
    </p>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
    <h1>Desenvolvido pelo grupo: Shadow - Para a semana Paulo Freire</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```